# Warning shown on opening devc++ after adding c++11 compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++, dev-c++

I wanted to use c++11 int devC++ so in compiler options->programs i added the phrase -std=c++11 and it worked just fine for me but after that each time i open devc++ this shows me  a warning like this
[Warning shown to me when opening dev C++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L9kf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Move the `-std=c++11` from the compiler program path to the compiler arguments. (That is, if Dev-C++ doesn't have any built-in way to specify the standard version.)

The compiler program is `g++.exe`. You want `-std=c++11` to be considered an option passed to that program, not part of the program file name. I'm surprised it worked initially at all!